Writing Recamans sequence recursion program, why does the counter keep moving up and down?
I'm trying to learn recursion. I've been trying to write the Recamans sequence with a recursive function.
#include <stdio.h>
int recursion(int inputnum){
        if (inputnum==0){
            printf("term %d, zero returned\n",inputnum);
            return 0; 
        }
        else {
            if ((recursion(inputnum-1)-inputnum)<0){
                printf("returning %d at term %d \n",(recursion(inputnum-1)+ inputnum),inputnum);
                return (recursion(inputnum-1)+inputnum);
            }
            else {
                printf("returning %d at term %d \n",(recursion(inputnum-1)- inputnum),inputnum);
                return (recursion(inputnum-1)-inputnum);
            }
        }
}
int main(void){
        int numberofterms;
        numberofterms=3;
        printf("%d",recursion(numberofterms));
    }

As far as I know, I know I need to set a base case for the function which will return the simplest value for the problem, and in the case of my program, the variable inputnum should be increasing after it reaches 0. However, the debugging statement I put {printf("term %d, zero returned\n",inputnum);} still keeps showing up after the inputnum value seems to have gone up. Would anyone kindly point out the problems in this program?

Now you should tell us how you calculate the Recamans sequence.  Is the base case recusion(0) supposed to be 0?  What is the value expected for input 1? etc  The result is a single number so I understand how that ties in with a sequence.

The first debug statement doesn't appear particular interesting just says that 0 is being returned.  Your 2nd debug statement is incorrect as you have two two different calls but only print the first expected value.

I made a mistake there. However, what I wanted to ask was that after inputnum becomes 0, recursion(0)-> recursion(1)... should be returned? Because when I run the code, the debugging statement in the (when inputnum==0) condition keeps popping up , which makes me wonder what is happening during this process.
